# Docker as SSH proxy with existing ssh key

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile

I am trying to migrate a SSH proxy (with VPN) server to docker as container.

Existing proxy command which works:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -W %h:%p -q awx-user@ssh.local"'
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y nano \
    iputils-ping \
    telnet \
    net-tools \
    iptables \
    iproute2 \
    ssh \
    sudo \
    openssh-server

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

RUN \
    groupadd -g 999 awx && useradd -u 999 -g awx -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash awx-user && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' && \
    echo "awx-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access to the awx-user user!" && \
    echo "awx-user user:";  su - awx-user -c id

RUN mkdir -p /home/awx-user/.ssh

COPY awx_id_rsa /home/awx-user/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN  echo "IdentityFile /home/awx-user/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

RUN apt-get clean

USER awx-user

RUN sudo chown awx-user:awx /home/awx-user/.ssh
RUN sudo chown awx-user:awx /home/awx-user/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN sudo chmod 700 /home/awx-user/.ssh
RUN sudo chmod 600 /home/awx-user/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN ssh-keyscan awx2.tmnet.dk > /home/awx-user/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN mkdir /home/awx-user/motionpro
RUN mkdir /home/awx-user/motionpro/app

COPY MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh /home/awx-user/motionpro/MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh

RUN sudo chmod +x /home/awx-user/motionpro/MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh
RUN printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
RUN sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local

WORKDIR /home/awx-user

EXPOSE 22
```

Docker run:

```
docker run --user awx-user --hostname motionpro --name motionpro --privileged --network awxcompose901_default -p 2201:22 --device /dev/net/tun --cap-add NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 -t -d motionpro /bin/bash -c "sudo ./motionpro/MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh --target /home/awx-user/motionpro/app > /dev/null && sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -D && bash"
```

Changing proxy command to:

```
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -p 2201 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -W %h:%p -q awx-user@awx.local"'
```

However I am unable to connect. I've taken a bunch of stuff from other dockerfiles but don't know how to solve anymore. Anybody got a suggestion?

Comment: `I am unable to connect` is a bit vague. It's always a goo idea to see WHY you can't connect, add `-vv` to ssh and show the output. Btw. You should try it first with a **minimal** example/dockerfile

Comment: @jeb You are right. Sometimes I think stackoverflow is full of experts that can easily spot the cause. I will simplify and check verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding the public key and correct configuration in sshd_config